# Difference between `appcfg update` and `mvn appengine:update`?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

What is the difference between `appcfg update` and `mvn appengine:update`?

[Java uploading modules documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Uploading_modules) says to use this command to upload:

```
appcfg update
```

But that same documentation has a link to [a Java getting-started instruction about uploading](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading) that says to do this:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

What is the difference between these two methods of uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is the same: to deploy the app to the App Engine.

`appcfg update` requires that you have the WAR built already, and you have to point the script to the WAR location.

`mvn appengine:update` performs a Maven build and then upload the app. Running the goal will compile, test, and package the app, and call `appcfg update` for you.